# Authorization and authenthication for WinForm application

Tags: c#, winforms, authorization

I'm starting to develop windows application and I've been looking around for some authenthication and authorization solution available, but no luck so far. I have to be able to allow admin create users and roles, assign users to roles and define access to controls on form for specified roles (button enabled/disabled etc).

Is there any solution out there or maybe someone could give me short description of solution he's using?

Adrian

Comment: I mean that roles and permissions over controls(buttons, text fields) can't be hardcoded, admin should be able to defined them through some interface

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Client Application Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384297.aspx) are useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Membership provider class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)

Comment: That's for web sites, not winforms applications.

Answer (score 0):

It depend, will this be within a network domain or will people be able to access the application over the internet. If it is you would be looking at windows authentication otherwise ASP.Net authentication would work well.  Look up the ASP.Net membershp provider as it would do a lot of the grunt work for you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Application will be installed on users computer.

Comment: Obviously, will that user be part of a network domain i.e will it be an application for a company or individual?

Comment: i suppose it could be used from external, but application itself would be a client for database server and i need authorization system on ui, which allows me to enable/disable some controls

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking on creating standard users, roles, permissions table schema, add contorls table and permission would be 'for a role on a control' and then in form loading event fire up a method to set Enabled proprerty of controls due to user's role's permissions. Is this good idea or i should took a hammer and get this out of my head (and if i should, please tell me why ;) )